# C strtok Problems

Tags: c, linked-list, strtok

I've got a linked list and trying to separate one of the values into two different variables. I start with the id variable which consists of `"0000:c29302"`, but I want to break the part of either side of `":"` into the `clientid` and token variable. 
When I run my code it enters the while loop in the split function but then just kind of crashes. Thanks!

```
typedef struct node {
    char *id;
    char *clientid;
    char *token;
    struct node * next;
} credentials;

void split(credentials * head, char *delim);

int main()
{
    credentials * head = NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(credentials));

    head->id = "0000:c29302";
    head->next = NULL;
    split(head, ":");
}

void split(credentials * head, char *delim)
{
    char *token;
    char *temp;
    credentials * current = head;
    while (current != NULL) { //THIS WHILE LOOP
        temp = current->id;
        token = strtok(temp, delim);
        while(token != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This happens, because `strtok()` modifies the string argument! Since you are using a string literal here, it is likely to be held in read only memory on your platform. So every attempt to modify it results in a "Segmentation Violation".

If you make sure, that your string is modifiable, for example by using

```
head->id = strdup("0000:c29302");
```

it should work as expected!

Comment: +1 That's why it's handy to compile with `-Wall`. I'm pretty sure compiler would warn you in case if you assign `const char *` to `char *`.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs In C the type of a string literal is `char []` so no, there is no warning here

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the function declaration:

```
char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)
```

you may notice that `delim` has type of the `const char *` but `str` has type `char *`.
This is because  **the contents of this string `str` are modified and broken into smaller strings (tokens)**.

`"0000:c29302"` is a string literal which content cannot be modified.

Any attempt   to modify string literal would typically cause run time error `"Segmentation Violation".`

Your `strtok` has to point to a memory location which can be modified.

Therefore, you should allocate the memory for it and copy your string literal into it.

You can use the `malloc`:

```
head->id = malloc(strlen("0000:c29302")+1); // 1 char more for string terminator
strcpy(head->id, "0000:c29302");
```

or use  `char * strdup(const char *str1);`

which returns a pointer to a null-terminated byte string, which is a duplicate of the string pointed to by `str1`.

```
head->id = strdup("0000:c29302");
```

In both cases the allocated memory for your string must be freed at some point to avoid a memory leak.